# setTitleColor forState is not working

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I am setting my button colors, but they don't change when touched.

```
[self.nextButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.nextButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

When tap the button nothing happens. I setup an an action and target which is being called so I know the button is actually being tapped.

Any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Comment: Is your button's title set with `setAttributedTitle:…` instead of `setTitle:…`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `UIControlStateHighlighted` instead of `UIControlStateSelected`.

For reference, see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlState):

- `UIControlStateHighlighted`: *A control enters this state when a touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up event.*
- `UIControlStateSelected`: *For many controls, this state has no effect on behavior or appearance.*